# Do you know what 15180 means in relation to timestamp?

Tags: solidity, defi, timestamp

I saw a staking smart contract made by BuildBear Dapp.
https://github.com/BuildBearLabs/Tutorials/blob/main/Staking-with-BuildBear/contracts/Staking.sol

```
// numDays = 30 or 90 or 120 Lockup Period
block.timestamp + (numDays * 15180)
```

Looking at line 44 of the code
Multiply the number of days to lock up by 15180.

What does this mean??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line represents the date that the staked Ether can be unlocked. This unlock date is the time of the block generation in addition to the days of being lockup  multiplied by 15180. I don't think the number 15180 has meaning in relation to timestamp, at least the source below did not explain it.

See: https://medium.com/buildbear/creating-a-staking-smart-contract-with-buildbear-57a21b424aed

Comment: Hmm... if the lockup is 30 days, it's not actually 30(day) * 60*60*24 seconds.
30 * 15180 seconds would be correct. 
I wondered why it was calculated x 15180....anyway thanks for the reply!